# PHP encrypt and decrypt function to python

Tags: python, php, python-3.x, encryption

I'm doing an integration with some server and they have provided me with their APi endpoints and the code example of how to do the integration.

In some step in the integration they require to encrypt the data before send it and decrypt the response. They provided me with the following code in PHP 7.3:

```
// function use for encryption
function encrypt($text, $key, $type, $iv = "0123456789abcdef",
$size = 16) {
$pad = $size - (strlen($text) % $size);
$padtext = $text . str_repeat(chr($pad), $pad);
$crypt = openssl_encrypt($padtext, "AES-256-CBC", base64_decode($key), OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv);
return base64_encode($crypt);

// function use for Decryption
function decrypt($crypt, $key, $type, $iv = "0123456789abcdef") {
$crypt = base64_decode($crypt);
$padtext = openssl_decrypt($crypt, "AES-256-CBC", base64_decode($key), OPENSSL_RAW_DATA | OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv);
$pad = ord($padtext
{
strlen($padtext) - 1});
if ($pad > strlen($padtext)) {
return false;
}

if (strspn($padtext, $padtext
{
strlen($padtext) - 1}, strlen($padtext) - $pad) != $pad) {
$text = "Error";
}

$text = substr($padtext, 0, -1 * $pad);
return $text;
}
```

My application is working with python and I'm trying to simulate the both functions in python, but i don't know much about PHP so here is what i did so far but i still commented some of the code that i don't know to to replace it in python.

Here is my python try:

```
from base64 import b64decode
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
def encrypt(text, key, type, iv = "0123456789abcdef",size = 16):
    pad = size - (len(text)%size)
    # padtext = text . str_repeat(chr(pad), pad)
    crypt=AES.new(padtext,AES.MODE_CBC,b64decode(key),iv)
    return b64decode(crypt)

def decrypt(crypt,key, type, iv = "0123456789abcdef"):
    crypt = b64decode(crypt)
    padtext = AES.new(crypt, AES.MODE_CBC, b64decode(key), iv)
    # $pad = ord($padtext
    # {
    #     strlen($padtext) - 1});
    # if ($pad > strlen($padtext)) {
    # return false;
    # }
    if pad > len(padtext):
        return False
    # if (strspn($padtext, $padtext
    # {
    # strlen($padtext) - 1}, strlen($padtext) - $pad) != $pad) {
    # $text = "Error";
    # }

    # text = substr(padtext, 0, -1 * pad)
    return text
```

Comment: Looks very much like PKCS#7 compatible padding to me. I don't know why they didn't just use that within PHP, maybe a leftover of when they were using `mcrypt` functions instead. In that case you probably can replace the code with <none>. Although you should of course call some methods that perform the actual encryption / decryption.

Comment: i don't understand, what do you mean by replace the code with <none> please?@MaartenBodewes

Comment: The padding / unpadding is very likely already performed by any encryption / decryption routines defined on the AES object. So you don't need to implement it separately. Currently you are not even encrypting / decrypting though.

Comment: ah you mean the padding part is not important so i can ignore calculating it? what about open ssl and using Crypto in python ?

Comment: No, I'm saying that the AES object will already do it for you. Which library you use is up to you. AES & CBC mode are standardized, so you should generally be able to get it to work.

Comment: I didn't work with AES before,
So regarding calculating padding text which is formed from the text that needed to be encrypted what should i use to do it ?

Comment: Just try and encrypt / decrypt, would you already? Come back if it doesn't work.

Comment: According to the `import` statement PyCryptodome should probably be used which does _not implicitly_ pad, but provide a [module to support PKCS7](https://pycryptodome.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/util/util.html#Crypto.Util.Padding.pad), so no need for a custom implementation. Most has already been said about the PHP code: openssl uses PKCS7 padding _by default_ (unless disabled with `OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING`). Also, the `encrypt` function of the PHP code returns the padded plaintext, which makes no sense (possibly a copy/paste error or a remnant from some testing).

Comment: @Topaco sorry i updated the PHP code, i was just editing it for testing purpose,now it's correct

Comment: @MaartenBodewes u say just do encrypt / decrypt so what is the meaning of the 4th line of the PHP code ?!

Comment: Hmm, I stand corrected. Uh, yeah, if it is supplied as a separate module then you do need to pad. [Wikipedia has a good section on padding for block cipher (modes of operation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)), and PKCS#7 is the commonly used default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Many tries it was very simple and i manged to get it to work

```
import base64
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto.Util.Padding import pad


class AESCipher(object):

    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = base64.b64decode(key)

    def encrypt(self, raw):
        raw = pad(bytes(raw.encode('utf-8')), 16)
        iv = b'0123456789abcdef'
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        return base64.b64encode(cipher.encrypt(raw))

    def decrypt(self, enc):
        enc = base64.b64decode(enc)
        iv = b'0123456789abcdef'
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        return cipher.decrypt(enc).decode('utf-8')
```

Comment: This isn't a good solution. keeping iv same will only produce same hash all the time. iv needs to be random at each encryption so produce different hash every time.

Comment: it's just for testing purposes, simulating the php